# SSD - Exceed manufacturer maximum capacity

Tags: memory, ssd, sata, m.2

My Laptop has an unused M.2 slot.
I contacted the manufacturer of my laptop and they said it supports up to 512 GB of SATA type SSD (actually they said just 128 GB, 256 GB and 512 GB) for expansion of my current 1 TB HDD.

The question is: If I want to buy an SSD of 1 TB how many chances I have to make it work anyway (if possible)?

An explanation of why these limitations exist would be welcome as well.

Thanks in advance.

Update 1:

The laptop is an Asus VivoBook 15 with i7-8550U processor.

Comment: Without telling us the brand and type of the laptop, you will have to trust the word of the manufacturer, who might be wrong. In case he isn't, the SSD would not work.

Comment: The laptop is an Asus VivoBook 15 with i7-8550U processor. (sorry, I still can't edit questions on Super User)

Comment: To my knowledge, you do not need reputation to edit your own questions.

Comment: Yeah, you were right.

Comment: Does the manufacturer document the maximum physical dimensions of the M.2 stick? They come in at least three different lengths.

Comment: No they doesn't... do you think it can depend on that?

Comment: You could just [measure the dimensions of the m.2 slot](https://www.delock.de/infothek/M.2/M.2_e.html) though - 2280 = 22mm x 80mm. Limitations are usually due to crap firmware or rubbish controller chip perhaps. Sometimes you can update BIOS/firmware to support later (bigger) versions - depends on the manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you Smock, but I'm just collecting information for when the warranty of the laptop expires or it becomes necessary to get an SSD, for now. In the mean time is there any way to check if BIOS/firmware could be the problem, regardless of the dimension?